# Is there any way to use "File" as a data type in NestJs and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, nestjs

The working stack is ReactJs Graphql NestJs. Type **File** is working nicely on React side. But unable to catch that variable at NestJs side. As I'm unable to declare **File** data type in my DTO.

The error is: Undefined type error. Make sure you are providing an explicit type for the "image".

Is there any way to declare **File** as data type? or anyother work around for this?

Comment: What does the `File` type represent? Node doesn't have a built in `File`, it has `Buffer`s and `Stream`s

Comment: I have a File type object (that is actually an Image). I want to receive it at NestJs backend. But DW how to declare a Type File for it.

Comment: So you'll send it to the backend using a `multipart/form-data` request, and use something like `multer` to parse the request. `@types/multer` merges a `File` type onto the `express` namespace, `express.Multer.File` if I recall, that has the `buffer`, `originalfilename`, `filetype` and other useful metadata [File Upload docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload)

Comment: Okay got it. Let me try. Thanks

Comment: The main thing to keep in mind is that files are only concepts on the computer that holds them. Once you're at the point of sending a file somewhere, it's not a file anymore, it's just a bunch of bytes, so generally a server would not have a `File` type in quite the same way a client would.